# Env variable is not set correctly after update Jenkins version

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables

I have Jenkins V2.7 with a freestyle project running on Windows 7,
One of the build steps is “Execute Windows batch command”, in this step I run some .exe which do some stuff and also set environment variable TEST to Z:\DATA
Recently I have updated Jenkins and plugins to V2.144 and now when I run the job the TEST variable is set to Z:DATA instead of Z:\DATA

Any idea what can cause this issue ?

Comment: Have you tried adding another backslash to the path (Z:\\DATA)?

Comment: I tried this but it didn't helped, but for some reason I don't have this issue after converting the job to declarative Pipeline.
But currently I have a different issue, when I run the exe in the pipeline it successfully set the environment variable but the new value is not reloaded by the pipeline so rest of it is using the old value of env variable. Any ideas ?

Comment: I believe your exe should save that value to file and you should inject that as environment variable in the pipeline.